# GKE Private Clusters still have a Public Endpoint?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I created a private cluster in GKE, with no public endpoint access. And indeed, the "endpoint" it shows in the Web Console is a private 1918 address.  But when I get the low-level info for the cluster, I see that it still has a public endpoint:

```
privateClusterConfig:
  enablePrivateNodes: true
  masterIpv4CidrBlock: 172.16.1.0/28
  peeringName: gke-1921aee31283146cdde5-9bae-9cf1-peer
  privateEndpoint: 172.16.1.2
  publicEndpoint: 34.68.128.12
```

Is this a concern?  Is there any way to create a private cluster with *no* public endpoint?

Comment: Have you tried using `setPublicEndpoint` and setting it to `null`?

Comment: What I did was "create a private cluster with no client access to the public endpoint", a la: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#private_cp
I did not attempt any follow-up commands.